# Setar dificuldade para uma questão e ao selecionar a dificuldade buscar somente aquelas questões

Tags: c#, unity3d, game

Boa tarde!

Estou finalizando um Quiz em C# feito em Unity. A dúvida que tenho é, tenho várias questões que gero via um Asset. Porém eu preciso setar as dificuldades para cada uma das questões. E ao clicar no menu na dificuldade Fácil, quero que ele carregue somente aquelas questões que estão com a dificuldade selecionada. Porém ando tendo dificuldade. Vou colocar aqui o código da minha classe que cria a pergunta.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif


[CreateAssetMenuAttribute]

public class QuizQuestion : ScriptableObject {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    //Campos que receberão dados do arquivo .xml ou .json
    [SerializeField]
    private string pergunta;
    [SerializeField]
    private string[] respostas;
    [SerializeField]
    private int respostaCorreta;

    //Métodos para buscar as perguntas, opções, resposta correta e dificuldade
    public string Pergunta { get { return pergunta; } }
    public string[] Respostas { get { return respostas; } }
    public int RespostaCorreta { get { return respostaCorreta; } }

    //public int Dificuldade {  get { return dificuldade; } }

    public bool Asked { get; internal set; }

    //Validar a resposta
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (respostaCorreta > respostas.Length)
        {
            respostaCorreta = 0;
        }

       RenomearObjetoDeAcordoComPerguntaResposta();
    }

    private void RenomearObjetoDeAcordoComPerguntaResposta()
    {
        string desiredName = string.Format("{0} [{1}]",
            pergunta.Replace("?", ""),
            respostas[respostaCorreta]);

        string assetPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(this.GetInstanceID());
        string shouldEndWith = "/" + desiredName + ".asset";
        if (assetPath.EndsWith(shouldEndWith) == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Want to rename to " + desiredName);
            AssetDatabase.RenameAsset(assetPath, desiredName);
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        }
    }
}
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Não vejo nenhum atributo relacionado ao nível de dificuldade da `Pergunta`

Answer (score 0):

Tudo bem?

Você pode criar referência para as questões, com números, por exemplo. Vamos supor que na lista há 30 questões e estão divididos nas 3 dificuldades: fácil(1), médio(2) e difícil(3).

Então o jogador escolhe a dificuldade, logo (pseudo-código):

```
 \\aqui é a variavel que recebe a escolha da dificuldade
 int escolha_do_jogador = escolha;

  \\aqui analisa a escolha, no caso, a escolha é 1, logo, é a dificuldade facil.
 if(escolha do jogador == 1)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i <= 10;i++)
       {
          \\as questões faceis, neste caso, são as 10 primeiras da lista
          exibirQuestao = questao[i]; 
       }
    }
     \\dificuldade media
 if(escolha do jogador == 2)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i <= 10;i++)
       {
           \\aqui, a dificuldade media está de 10 a 20
          exibirQuestao = questao[i+10]; 
       }
    }
 if(escolha do jogador == 3)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i <= 10;i++)
       {
          \\aqui, a dificuldade esta no dificil, de 20 a 30
          exibirQuestao = questao[i+20]; 
       }
    }
```

É um código de exemplo, adapte seu código a esse pensamento.